# With utf8mb4 collation different characters are equal in "where" condition

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

Field 'name' is utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. When I query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `name` = 'kliutys'
```

selects records with the value 'kliūtys'. How to make mysql select just exact match and treat 'ū' as different character than 'u'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing `tags` column collation to `utf8mb4_bin`.

Other option would be specifying collation in select:

`` SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `name` COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = 'kliutys' ``

More info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html